# java.net.SocketException in simple Kubernetes pod

Tags: java, sockets, kubernetes, port, ping

#### TL;DR

java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed) in simple Kubernetes pod that can curl to the internet.

#### Short Description

I've setup a simple Job object in Kubernetes, which spawns a simple pod to use the Slack-Api to poll for a conversation history via slack.

Running this application locally or dockerized works like a charm. But when trying to execute it in Kubernetes I get a

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:120)
```

#### Kubernetes config

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-app-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: name
              image: myimage
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              ports:
                - containerPort: 443
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 80
                  protocol: TCP
              env:
                - name: http_proxy
                  value: myproxy
                - name: https_proxy
                  value: myproxy
                - name: no_proxy
                  value: myproxy
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Trying to debug what is happening, I noticed that I could curl something from my pod (so there's access to the public internet) but when I try to ping, i get Socket: Operation not permitted.

Eg:

```
bash-4.2$ ping www.google.com
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
bash-4.2$ curl -I www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
p3p: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
date: Wed, 29 Sep 2021 09:18:36 GMT
server: gws
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
expires: Wed, 29 Sep 2021 09:18:36 GMT
cache-control: private
set-cookie: XXXXXXXXXXX
expires=Thu, 31-Mar-2022 09:18:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
x-cache: MISS from XXXXXXXXXXX
x-cache-lookup: MISS fXXXXXXXXX

bash-4.2$ command terminated with exit code 137
```

I believe that I'm missing some configuration. I tried opening a port with a `NodePort` service but I had no success. Any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not inherit the proxy settings from the environment.

You need to specify the proxy using Java system properties

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=locahost -Dhttp.proxyPort=9900
```

Comment: Tried setting java to inherit proxy settings with  `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true`
but didn't work. 

I think the key is that the ping socket is also blocked.

Comment: In the end, slack api uses Okhttp3 which ignores -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true and uses the explicit properties only.